# How to make Ethereum storage more efficient?

Tags: solidity

I have coded the contract -

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract CollegeAdmin {
    uint public studentAge=18;
    uint public studentIncome=15000;
    uint public studentScore=4;
    uint public studentAttendance=96;
    event changedAge(uint age);

    function setAge(uint age) public {
        studentAge = age;
        changedAge(age);
    }

}
```

And in testing I find -

> eth.getStorageAt(con.address,0)
>       "0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005a"
>   eth.getStorageAt(con.address,1)
>       "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003a98"
>   eth.getStorageAt(con.address,2)
>       "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004"
>   eth.getStorageAt(con.address,3)
>       "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000060"
>   eth.getStorageAt(con.address,4)
>       "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"

There is obviously a lot of wasted storage. Is there a way to avoid so much waste. Is this a matter of coding structs or coding different types of integer?

I want to eliminate storing so many leading zeros in the storage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`uint` is an alias for `uint256`, so each takes 32 bytes. If you don't need that big of a number, you can use a different type, like `uint32`. Solidity will pack multiple values into a single 32-byte word when it can. See https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/miscellaneous.html#layout-of-state-variables-in-storage.